# Cordova AutoStart in Background

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing an `ionic cordova` application. I want my app to auto start on ios and to remain in background. The app should be able to receive push notifications and to scan for bluetooth while being in background. I have checked `ToniKorin/cordova-plugin-autostart` plugin, but it only works on android not on ios.

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set an app to start automatically into iPhone using Cordova, generally iOS apps do not start with the system, and there is no way to make them do so. One exception is made, for VOIP-enabled apps to establish connections and begin listening for incoming calls, all apps with the appropriate plist keys are launched on system startup, then backgrounded without user interaction. This behavior is [documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1).

In the iPhone Native apps you can set [BootLaunch - an iOS startup app](https://github.com/lithium3141/BootLaunch) to setup your apps to launch an app when booting an iOS device.

Comment: i can see now the difference with html5 mobile app and native app

Comment: Yes, we can consider this as a drawback of a hybrid app that we cannot apply all the native functionality into it.